# Get object from ListView's ListItem on click

Tags: listview, javafx-8

I have a list view populated with an observable list

```
availableSymbolsTable.setItems(watch.GetAvailableSymbols());
```

The cell factory:

```
availableSymbolsTable.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Symbol>, ListCell<Symbol>>()
        {

            @Override
            public ListCell<Symbol> call(ListView<Symbol> p)
            {
                final ListCell<Symbol> cell = new ListCell<Symbol>()
                {
                    @Override
                    protected void updateItem(Symbol t, boolean bln)
                    {
                        if (t != null)
                        {
                            setText(t.getSymbolName());
                        }

                        setOnMouseEntered(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void handle(MouseEvent event)
                            {
                                //This works
                                System.out.println("index: " + getIndex());
                            }
                        });

                        setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
                        {
                            @Override
                            public void handle(MouseEvent event)
                            {
                                 //HERE getItem() always returns null
                                System.out.println( getItem().getSymbolName());         
                            }
                        });
                    }

                };
                return cell;}});}
```

In the MouseClicked event handler, the getItem() method always returns null. How can I get the associated Symbol object?

EDIT:
If it helps: I dont know the expected behaviour, but when clicked, elements do not become selected. This happens event when I comment out mouseClicked and mouseEntered handlers. Mouse clicks do nothing.

Comment: Educate me please - why the downvotes?

Comment: The issue with selection is because you forgot to call `super.updateItem(t, bln);`. That needs to be the first line of your `updateItem(...)` method.

Comment: @James_D  This solves the selection AND my original question. You should post it as an answer. Thanks.

Comment: @UlukBiy is correct though: you should not repeatedly update the handler in the `updateItem(...)` method.

Comment: @James_D I took his answer into consideration also. Combining your two answers, the list view is behaving as I expect it to - changing selections and fetching items in click event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have omitted two important things in your `updateItem(...)` method:

1. You *must* call `super.updateItem(...)`. This is required in order to properly maintain the state of the `item` and `empty` properties, as well as handle things such as setting the CSS pseudo class states for selection and focus
2. You must handle the case where the cell is empty (or the item is null), and clear the text in that case.

Additionally, as pointed out in Uluk Biy's answer, it is not a good idea to set the handlers in the `updateItem(...)` method. This method is called frequently, and the handlers only need to be set once when the cell is created.

So your cell factory should look like

```
availableSymbolsTable.setCellFactory( new Callback<ListView<Symbol>, ListCell<Symbol>>()
{
    @Override
    public ListCell<Symbol> call( ListView<Symbol> p )
    {
        final ListCell<Symbol> cell = new ListCell<Symbol>()
        {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem( Symbol t, boolean empty )
            {
                super.updateItem(t, empty);
                if (empty) {
                    setText(null);
                } else {
                    setText( t.getSymbolName() );
                }
            }
        };

        cell.setOnMouseEntered( new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle( MouseEvent event )
            {
                System.out.println( "index: " + cell.getIndex() );
            }
        } );

        cell.setOnMouseClicked( new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle( MouseEvent event )
            {
                if ( cell.getItem() != null )
                {
                    System.out.println( cell.getItem().getSymbolName() );
                }
            }
        } );

        return cell;
    }
} );
```

As an aside, since you are using JavaFX 8, you can vastly simplify this code by using Lambda expressions:

```
availableSymbolsTable.setCellFactory(lv -> {
    ListCell<Symbol> cell = new ListCell<Symbol>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Symbol t, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(t, empty);
            if (empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(t.getSymbolName());
            }
        }
    };

    cell.setOnMouseEntered(e -> {
        System.out.println("Index: "+cell.getIndex());
    });

    cell.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
        if (cell.getItem() != null) {
            System.out.println(cell.getItem().getSymbolName());
        }
    });

    return cell ;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't set the listener in a `updateItem()` method, since it will be called multiple times while rendering the list cells, you don't want to set them unnecessarily over again. Moreover in some cases of `updateItem()` the `item` will be null, i.e. the cell will be empty, and hence `getItem()` will return null.

Try

```
availableSymbolsTable.setCellFactory( new Callback<ListView<Symbol>, ListCell<Symbol>>()
{
    @Override
    public ListCell<Symbol> call( ListView<Symbol> p )
    {
        final ListCell<Symbol> cell = new ListCell<Symbol>()
        {
            @Override
            protected void updateItem( Symbol t, boolean bln )
            {
                super.updateItem(t, empty);

                if ( t != null )
                {
                    setText( t.getSymbolName() );
                }
                else
                {
                    setText( null );
                }
            }
        };

        cell.setOnMouseEntered( new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle( MouseEvent event )
            {
                System.out.println( "index: " + cell.getIndex() );
            }
        } );

        cell.setOnMouseClicked( new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
        {
            @Override
            public void handle( MouseEvent event )
            {
                if ( cell.getItem() != null )
                {
                    System.out.println( cell.getItem().getSymbolName() );
                }
            }
        } );

        return cell;
    }
} );
```

Note also that the user may select the list item with keyboard, and if you want to handle them also, it is more appropriate to observe `selectedItemProperty`:

```
availableSymbolsTable.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Symbol>()
{
    @Override
    public void changed( ObservableValue<? extends Symbol> observable, Symbol oldValue, Symbol newValue )
    {
        System.out.println( "newValue = " + newValue );
    }
});
```

Comment: Using your code (with additional (Symbol)cell.getItem() cast in onMOuseClicked) the code never enters the if statement because cell.getItem() is always false.

Comment: I will try using selectedItemProperty. How should I handle double clicks in that case. Say that I want to the same action on double click and enter key (when an item is selected). BTW, thanks for your effor so far.

Comment: And again... you must call `super.updateItem(...)`, else the `item` property will not actually be set correctly.

Comment: Thanks @James_D. I totally missed that.